# How can loop animations with a different start and end point in after effects?

Tags: animation

I use normally: `loopOut('cycle')` expression to loop a movement. But sometimes I want to loop an animation like this:

- 1-3 frames -> rotation 30deg
- 3x loop a full rotation
- after looping -> add 10 other frames and
- make rotation 120deg

How is it possible to loop between this actions and not using copy+paste?

Here is a link [to my work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_kLMfuXxp5ELVF5Ykxvc2FXTDA/view?usp=sharing)

I loop the arms motion, but as you see in the first frames the left arm has to wait until the right arm does the first half of the motion. If I add a half motion to the left arm I can't loop it. I would have to avoid copy+paste because I want to loop it 40 times. At the end of my animation I also need a different motion with the right or left because the swimmer has to touch the wall with two hands. I hope, I was clear.

Comment: Welcome jeki :) Could you add a example comp or some images to your question to understand your issue exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Using time remapping could be a solution. You animate one full circle of the animation and precompose this. Then you time remap that layer and use loopOut('cycle').